# Concurrent mode failure even when memory is getting reclamied

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-7, concurrent-mark-sweep

Here is VM OPS of my application

```
-Xms7500m
-Xmx7500m
-Xmn4g
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=80
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:ConcGCThreads=6
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintGCCause
-verbose:gc
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Concurrent mode exception occurred 3 times in 5 days. App is still running file and memory too is available.

```
2020-04-16T18:57:47.575-0400: 100509.755: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2020-04-16T18:57:51.701-0400: 100513.881: [GC (Allocation Failure)2020-04-16T18:57:51.702-0400: 100513.881: [ParNew (promotion failed)
Desired survivor size 343565920 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:   91240280 bytes,   91240280 total
- age   2:   52703592 bytes,  143943872 total
- age   3:   26770336 bytes,  170714208 total
- age   4:   29495504 bytes,  200209712 total
- age   5:    9595480 bytes,  209805192 total
- age   6:   24205808 bytes,  234011000 total
: 3710667K->3614781K(3774912K), 1.1252750 secs]2020-04-16T18:57:52.827-0400: 100515.007: [CMS CMS: abort preclean due to time 2020-04-16T18:57:52.894-0400: 100515.074: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 4.174/5.319 secs] [Times: user=14.39 sys=0.29, real=5.32 secs]
(concurrent mode failure): 3227087K->1442206K(3485696K), 8.0583310 secs] 6926256K->1442206K(7260608K), [CMS Perm : 105501K->105321K(176020K)], 9.1844190 secs] [Times: user=9.41 sys=0.01, real=9.18 secs]
--
2020-04-19T18:05:09.581-0400: 356551.761: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2020-04-19T18:05:11.759-0400: 356553.939: [GC (Allocation Failure)2020-04-19T18:05:11.760-0400: 356553.939: [ParNew (promotion failed)
Desired survivor size 343565920 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:   95822816 bytes,   95822816 total
- age   2:   24589528 bytes,  120412344 total
- age   3:   28175272 bytes,  148587616 total
- age   4:   24536120 bytes,  173123736 total
- age   5:   23041104 bytes,  196164840 total
- age   6:   12194152 bytes,  208358992 total
: 3670487K->3606232K(3774912K), 0.9360540 secs]2020-04-19T18:05:12.696-0400: 356554.875: [CMS2020-04-19T18:05:12.758-0400: 356554.938: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 2.224/3.177 secs] [Times: user=10.62 sys=0.17, real=3.18 secs]
(concurrent mode failure): 3233090K->1492098K(3485696K), 7.9204130 secs] 6896158K->1492098K(7260608K), [CMS Perm : 105666K->105467K(176212K)], 8.8569600 secs] [Times: user=9.08 sys=0.01, real=8.86 secs]
--
2020-04-22T19:07:04.975-0400: 619467.155: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0047280 seconds
2020-04-22T19:07:07.174-0400: 619469.354: [GC (Allocation Failure)2020-04-22T19:07:07.174-0400: 619469.354: [ParNew (promotion failed)
Desired survivor size 343565920 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:   98089096 bytes,   98089096 total
- age   2:   31239384 bytes,  129328480 total
- age   3:   29372368 bytes,  158700848 total
- age   4:   27791800 bytes,  186492648 total
- age   5:   19365904 bytes,  205858552 total
- age   6:   35928016 bytes,  241786568 total
: 3643909K->3678567K(3774912K), 0.9460110 secs]2020-04-22T19:07:08.121-0400: 619470.300: [CMS2020-04-22T19:07:08.234-0400: 619470.413: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 2.612/3.582 secs] [Times: user=12.78 sys=0.18, real=3.58 secs]
(concurrent mode failure): 3230258K->1503933K(3485696K), 8.8236640 secs] 6862317K->1503933K(7260608K), [CMS Perm : 105907K->105647K(176596K)], 9.7702040 secs] [Times: user=10.06 sys=0.00, real=9.77 secs]
```

App don't have FullGC in last one week

```
2020-04-15T15:03:29.193-0400: 51.372: [Full GC (Permanent Generation Full)2020-04-15T15:03:29.193-0400: 51.373: [CMS: 771051K->1044286K(3485696K), 4.2744340 secs] 1915012K->1044286K(7260608K), [CMS Perm : 101698K->101581K(102128K)], 4.2749400 secs] [Times: user=4.18 sys=0.11, real=4.28 secs]
```

Why Concurrent mode failure exceptions are coming when

1. No frequent Full GC
2. Memory is getting reclaimed after GC

   ```
   3227087K->1442206K(3485696K), 8.0583310 secs] 6926256K->1442206K(7260608K)
   3233090K->1492098K(3485696K), 7.9204130 secs] 6896158K->1492098K(7260608K)
   3230258K->1503933K(3485696K), 8.8236640 secs] 6862317K->1503933K(7260608K)
   ```

Node configuration: 8 core CPU, 12 GB RAM RHEL VM, JDK 1.7.0_45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From chapter 8 [**Concurrent Mark Sweep (CMS) Collector**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html) of the **Java Platform, Standard Edition HotSpot Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning Guide**:

> **Concurrent Mode Failure**
>
> The CMS collector uses one or more garbage collector threads that run simultaneously with the application threads with the goal of completing the collection of the tenured generation before it becomes full. As described previously, in normal operation, the CMS collector does most of its tracing and sweeping work with the application threads still running, so only brief pauses are seen by the application threads. However, if the CMS collector is unable to finish reclaiming the unreachable objects before the tenured generation fills up, or if an allocation cannot be satisfied with the available free space blocks in the tenured generation, then the application is paused and the collection is completed with all the application threads stopped. The inability to complete a collection concurrently is referred to as *concurrent mode failure* and **indicates the need to adjust the CMS collector parameters**. If a concurrent collection is interrupted by an explicit garbage collection (`System.gc()`) or for a garbage collection needed to provide information for diagnostic tools, then a concurrent mode interruption is reported.

It means that, at the time, your application was generating garbage faster than the collector threads could reclaim them, and/or was using so much CPU the collector threads didn't have time to finish the jobs.

Comment: CPU usage is not high ( < 50%).  If memory is getting reclaimed, why the error is thrown is my query

Comment: @Ravindrababu As I already said, **at the time**, your application was generating garbage faster than it was being reclaimed. Were you monitoring the CPU at 7:07 PM on April 22, 2020? If not, how would you know it was < 50%, *at that time*?

Comment: Monitored sar. 
19:00:01        all     22.48      0.00      0.85      0.00      0.00     76.67 19:10:01        all     23.84      0.00      0.92      0.02      0.00     75.22. So increasing young gen will address this issue?